# PanelGrid and OutputLabel

Tags: java, html, xml, jsf, primefaces

I got a problem with this code. I want to have a SelectOneMenu where I select a Customer (this one works fine for me). But after I selected an element, I should see the ID of this Customer in a OutputText. This does not work:

```
<h:form id="form">
  <h:panelGrid columns="2">
    <h:outputLabel for="customer" value="Customer: " />
    <h:selectOneMenu id="customerList"
    value="#{customerController.selected}" required="true">
      <f:selectItems value="#{customerController.items}"
      var="customer"
      itemLabel="#{customer.id} #{customer.firstname} #{customer.lastname} #{customer.email}"
      itemValue="customer" />
      <p:ajax update=":form:myId" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
    <h:outputLabel value="Customer ID: " for="myId" />
    <h:outputText id="myId"
    value="#{customerController.selected.id}" />
  </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Are you getting any log error?

Comment: Always post your backbean code.

Comment: Please read server logs and ajax response body and report back.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
<p:ajax update="myId" />
```

Comment: Problem solved today, lads. I had to use another Backing Bean. Anyway; thank you.